# How do I set up a second monitor (extended display) in Xfce?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xfce

I am using Xubuntu 15.04 on a Mid 2012 15" Macbook Pro. I have a second monitor of a different, smaller resolution that I would like to connect as an extension to my desktop using a mini-display port to VGA adapter and a thunderbolt port, yet whenever I go to display settings, the monitor does not show up when I switch it on.

I have tried running `xrandr` in the terminal and ARandR, yet neither of them were able to detect the monitor. I also have a third monitor that I tried to use with the same connection to test if it there was a problem with the monitor itself, yet it didn't work either.

I am using the Nvidia proprietary graphics driver. My GPUs are Nvidia Geforce GTX 650 and Intel HD 4000 Graphics.

Comment: You could try booting your install disk/flash drive to see if the open-source option works. Support for those graphics should be built right in to the Linux kernel. You could also try booting an install disk with Xubuntu 14.04 instead to see if the LTS version works for your graphics card. It may also make a difference to make sure that both screens are using the same card.

Comment: I have no idea what I did, but somehow the monitor just randomly started working. I didn't even do anything or change any settings. All I did was log back in a bunch of times. It worked for a few logins, but then I logged out and it stopped working. It looks like that the monitors are both using the Nvidia Geforce GTX 650 card.

Comment: I am now using the open source drivers. The monitor isn't displaying anything after my reboot. Hopefully it will start to work again anyway... Are there any more ideas that I could try in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, my other monitor can't be used unless I suspend the system before I log in.

Every time I suspend, the monitor is able to work as an extended display (after I configure the settings). If I don't suspend, then the monitor will not function at all. It would be nice if I didn't have to suspend and configure the settings every time I want to use the monitor, but for now this has been able to work as a temporary solution.